# Create customer attribute not working in magento 2

Tags: php, magento2

I'm trying to create a customer attribute on magento 2.0.1. I have checked all the answered questions here but my code still does not work.

Here my InstallData.php located in Mymodule\Cus\Setup

```
namespace Mymodule\Cus\Setup;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
   */
       class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
 {

/**
 * @var CustomerSetupFactory
 */
protected $customerSetupFactory;

/**
 * @var AttributeSetFactory
 */
private $attributeSetFactory;

/**
 * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
 * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
    AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
) {
    $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
}


/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{

    /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
    $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

    /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
    $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
    $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

    $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'test_att', [
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'label' => 'Test ATT',
        'input' => 'text',
        'required' => false,
        'visible' => true,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'sort_order' => 1000,
        'position' => 1000,
        'system' => 0,
    ]);

    $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'test_att')
        ->addData(['attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer','adminhtml_customer_address','customer_account_edit','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address','adminhtml_checkout'],
        ]);

    $attribute->save();


}
}
```

When i run both :
php bin\magento setup:upgrade
php bin\magento setup:flush

the attribute is not created.

My module is registrated and i'm using for others things and it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to locate Setup folder in the root of module also do not forget change namespace in the file

Try to clean row in the db setup_module table with your module version

Try to create attribute in this way:

```
$eavTable = $installer->getTable('needded table');

$columns = [
            'column_name' => [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'nullable' => false,
                'comment' => '',
            ],
        ];
$connection = $installer->getConnection();

foreach ($columns as $name => $definition) {
    $connection->addColumn($eavTable, $name, $definition);
}
```

Comment: Which table in db should i change the version of my module with ?

Comment: version information is stored on setup_module table

Comment: I didn't find any "setup_module" table in the database .. what am i missing here ?

Comment: Thank you. The attribute is created but now it's  not saved when i do setAttribute.

Comment: it's a separate problem, hope you do not forget to clean the cache